# Go converting ptypes/struct Value to BSON

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, bson, mongo-go, protobuf-go

### Requirements

Two services:

- **Server** - for writing blog posts to MongoDB
- **Client** - sends request to the first service

The blog post has `title` of type `string`, and `content` which is a dynamic type - can be any JSON value.

### Protobuf

```
syntax = "proto3";

package blog;

option go_package = "blogpb";

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Blog {
  string id = 1;
  string title = 2;
  google.protobuf.Value content = 3;
}

message CreateBlogRequest {
  Blog blog = 1;
}

message CreateBlogResponse {
  Blog blog = 1;
}

service BlogService {
  rpc CreateBlog (CreateBlogRequest) returns (CreateBlogResponse);
}
```

Let's start with protobuf message, which meats requirements - `string` for `title` and any JSON value for `content`.

### Client

```
package main

import (...)

func main() {
    cc, _ := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure())
    defer cc.Close()
    c := blogpb.NewBlogServiceClient(cc)

    var blog blogpb.Blog

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"title": "First example", "content": "string"}`), &blog)
    c.CreateBlog(context.Background(), &blogpb.CreateBlogRequest{Blog: &blog})

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"title": "Second example", "content": {"foo": "bar"}}`), &blog)
    c.CreateBlog(context.Background(), &blogpb.CreateBlogRequest{Blog: &blog})
}
```

The client sends two requests to the server - one with `content` having `string` type, and other with the `object`. No errors here.

### Server

```
package main

import (...)

var collection *mongo.Collection

type server struct {
}

type blogItem struct {
    ID      primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title   string             `bson:"title"`
    Content *_struct.Value     `bson:"content"`
}

func (*server) CreateBlog(ctx context.Context, req *blogpb.CreateBlogRequest) (*blogpb.CreateBlogResponse, error) {
    blog := req.GetBlog()

    data := blogItem{
        Title:   blog.GetTitle(),
        Content: blog.GetContent(),
    }

    // TODO: convert "data" or "data.Content" to something that could be BSON encoded..

    res, err := collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    oid, _ := res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)

    return &blogpb.CreateBlogResponse{
        Blog: &blogpb.Blog{
            Id:      oid.Hex(),
            Title:   blog.GetTitle(),
            Content: blog.GetContent(),
        },
    }, nil

}

func main() {
    client, _ := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    client.Connect(context.TODO())
    collection = client.Database("mydb").Collection("blog")
    lis, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:50051")
    s := grpc.NewServer([]grpc.ServerOption{}...)
    blogpb.RegisterBlogServiceServer(s, &server{})
    reflection.Register(s)
    go func() { s.Serve(lis) }()
    ch := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(ch, os.Interrupt)
    <-ch
    client.Disconnect(context.TODO())
    lis.Close()
    s.Stop()
}
```

And here I get:

> cannot transform type main.blogItem to a BSON Document: no encoder
>   found for structpb.isValue_Kind

What do I expect? To see the exact value of content in MongoDB, something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5f6f75d2679d058eb9ef79"), "title" : "Second example", "content": "string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5f6f75d2679d058eb9ef78"), "title" : "First example", "content": { "foo": "bar" } }
```

I guess I need to transform `data.Content` in the line where I added `TODO:`...

I can create github repo with this example if that could help.

Comment: I think you need to marshal the Content to others type which mongodb driver can understand such as Json. https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb#JSONPBMarshaler. Or you can write your custome encoder to support structpb

Comment: I have a feeling that you are correct :))) However I'm new to golang, and I'm struggling with these doing it. But I will try! thanks

Comment: Hey @nguyenhoai890! I succeeded to get the result I want with your suggested lib!

Comment: Great! Can you post your marshal code in this page for ref?

Comment: I will, and you can copy/paste it if you want - so I will mark it as accepted answer

Comment: As you see I do `structpb.Value` => `string` => `interface{}` converting. What do you think - maybe it would be possible to convert `structpb` => `interface{}` ?

Comment: I never use the proto.Value so don't have much idea to improve your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as suggested by @nguyenhoai890 in the comment I managed to fix it using `jsonpb` lib - first `MarshalToString` to covert from `structpb` to `string(json)` and then `json.Unmarshal` to convert from `string(json)` to `interface{}` which is supported by BSON. Also I had to fix a Client to correctly unmarshal from string to protobuf.

### Client

```
func main() {
    cc, _ := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure())
    defer cc.Close()
    c := blogpb.NewBlogServiceClient(cc)

    var blog blogpb.Blog
    jsonpb.UnmarshalString(`{"title": "Second example", "content": {"foo": "bar"}}`, &blog)
    c.CreateBlog(context.Background(), &blogpb.CreateBlogRequest{Blog: &blog})

    jsonpb.UnmarshalString(`{"title": "Second example", "content": "stirngas"}`, &blog)
    c.CreateBlog(context.Background(), &blogpb.CreateBlogRequest{Blog: &blog})
}
```

### Server

```
type blogItem struct {
    ID      primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title   string             `bson:"title"`
    Content interface{}        `bson:"content"`
}

func (*server) CreateBlog(ctx context.Context, req *blogpb.CreateBlogRequest) (*blogpb.CreateBlogResponse, error) {
    blog := req.GetBlog()

    contentString, err := new(jsonpb.Marshaler).MarshalToString(blog.GetContent())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var contentInterface interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(contentString), &contentInterface)

    data := blogItem{
        Title:   blog.GetTitle(),
        Content: contentInterface,
    }

    res, err := collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    oid, _ := res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)

    return &blogpb.CreateBlogResponse{
        Blog: &blogpb.Blog{
            Id:      oid.Hex(),
            Title:   blog.GetTitle(),
            Content: blog.GetContent(),
        },
    }, nil

}
```